# sql server: take address extension into different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some address numbers that I need to split, currently the format is like:

```
col a: 42A
col b: NULL
```

I want to put the addressextension in column B, and remove it from A. What's the easiest way to do this in MS Sql?
So an update statement that removes the value (in the example: 'A') from column A, and puts them in clumn B, and keeps the number in A. –

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Can we assume you mean an update to the rows? Where column B IS NULL,  but column A IS NOT NULL.

Comment: I mean an update indeed, apologies! 
So an update statement that removes the value (in the example: 'A') from column A, and puts them in clumn B, and keeps the number in A.

Comment: what is the rules & condition of your `split`

Comment: Please share your raw data and expected output with conditions

Comment: update yourtable set cola=substring(cola, 1,len(cola)-1),colb=substring(cola,len(cola),len(cola)) where colb is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be below query will help you.

```
create table yourtable (
    cola varchar(10), colb varchar(10)
    )
;

insert into yourtable
values ('42a', NULL)

insert into yourtable
values ('42aa', NULL)

insert into yourtable
values ('42aaa', NULL)

insert into yourtable
values ('442aaa', NULL)


UPDATE yourtable
SET cola = LEFT(cola, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', cola )) 
,colb= LTRIM(RIGHT(cola, LEN(cola) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', cola ))) 

select  *
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an update, but take care to set colb first, then you can set cola to null.

e.g.

```
create table yourtable (
    cola varchar(10), colb varchar(10)
    )
;

insert into yourtable
values ('42a', NULL)
;

select  *
from yourtable
;

| cola | colb |
+------+------+
| 42a  | NULL |


update yourtable
set colb = cola
, cola = NULL
where cola IS NOT NULL
and colb IS NULL
;

select
*
from yourtable
;

| cola | colb |
+------+------+
| NULL | 42a  |
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for you response, i think i may have been unclear, I mean to just move the letter to another column. For example, in COLA =42A, and COLB should be: 'A' after the statement, and COLA should just be 42. (length of numbers is variable)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the structure of ColA is permanent and it has 2digits plus one character always, you can simply run this query:

```
UPDATE [yourTable] SET COLA = SUBSTRING(COLA,1,2) , COLB = substring(COLA,3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the follwing:

```
CREATE TABLE [yourtable]
([cola] VARCHAR(10), 
 [colb] VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO [yourtable]
VALUES
('42a', 
 NULL
);


SELECT *
FROM   [yourtable];

UPDATE [yourtable]
  SET  
     [colb] = RIGHT([cola], 1), 
     [cola] = LEFT([cola], 2)
WHERE  [cola] = '42a';
```

Comment: Answer from @Nikunj is probably the most versatile solution.